# Changing the color of scale and rotation points when editing a feature

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, scale, vertices, rotate

When selecting a feature in my application and selecting the edit button the selected features become editable. This means that the points for scaling and rotation of that feature are made visible as well as the point for editing the current vertices and creating new ones. Since the points for scaling and rotating vertices are white in color as well as the points to create new vertices for that features, I was wondering whether there may be a way to change the color for one of them to have them stand out. I cannot seem to find any information regarding whether this can be done.

Comment: Are you asking about the 3.x or 4.x JS API?

Comment: I'm asking about the 3.x JS API